# iOS - limit on UIView animate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, uiviewanimation

So I'm making a simple trivia game and I have a timerView that shrinks as time passes. When the user selects an answer, it needs to stop shrinking immediately - it must be very responsive. I give the user 10 seconds per question. Originally I would animate 10 times (with a duration of 1.0f), calling the next "segment" of animation in the completion block of the previous animation. In the completion block I would check to see if the user has tapped an answer, and if so I don't continue the chain. That solution works fine except that it's not very responsive because it's on a per second basis-- user taps an answer at the start of the second segment and the bar has a noticeable continuation.

My solution to THAT problem was to instead have 1000 animation calls with a duration of 0.01f. After doing that, the responsiveness was on point - the view stops animating as soon as I tap an answer -- the issue though, is that it's not actually 10 seconds, it takes more like 20.

So question number 1: what's the smallest time interval animateWithDuration can actually process properly?

Question number 2: is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

ill answer question two: yes there definitely is a better way, have a look at [CADisplayLink](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/index.html)

use it to shrink your view a little bit each frame, and end the display link when you need to

Answer (score 0):

the most responsive way is: the user taps an answer, you response in the touch callback, remove animations. you can remove animations by `CALayer`'s `removeAllAnimations` method

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to set the view to shrinking using a single animation with linear timing, and then set the speed of the view's layer to 0 to pause the animation. When you set the speed on the layer to 0 the animation pauses instantly.

This works because under the covers, UIView animation actually creates and installs CAAnimation objects on the view's layers. It's possible to pause and continue an in-flight UIView animation just like you can a CAAnimation.

I have a project called [**KeyframeViewAnimations**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/KeyframeViewAnimations) (link) on github that allows you to pause, continue, or "scrub" UIView and CAAnimations back and forth with a slider. You could use that technique. The tricky bit will be figuring out how far along the animation is.